# Synchronization from class Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, class

I have a question about multithreading in Delphi.
Suppose, I have a thread and I have a some class, that do some work and must have synchronization. How I can make it?
I make this procedure (In ThreadClass):

```
procedure TThreadClass.SynchProc(P: TProc);
begin
 ...
 Synchronize(TThreadProcedure(P));
 ...
end;
```

And I call it from my class, that running in Thread, but ...
In procedure symbol "Synchonization" is a method of TThread, that is object "(Self as TThread)", but when I call it proc from my class, variable "Self" doesn't contain a my ThreadClass object (I dont know, that it's contained, may be object of second class, that running in Thread). respectively that procedure does not work. 
I search oth variants (I'm passed my threadClass object to second class object and try to call "Synchronization" procedure from procedure of second class, but compiller did not want to compile it).

Can you help me? Will be grateful for any help

with greetings from Ukraine
PS Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Modern Delphi has class procedure versions of `Synchronize`. Do you even need `Synchronize`? That runs the code on the main thread. There's always the option of using locks to serialize. You should tell us what `TThreadClass` is.

Comment: I call my thread from main thread of programm because I need to perform (may be it's call "perform" in English) many operations. But I need to use form's components too - to view operation progress etc. I need to focus on edit to ask user for some things, wait for user answer and continue performing. That's cannot be realized without synch, imho.

Comment: If you need to synch to main thread then yes you need to call TThread.Synchronize. If you are creating a thread surely you can just do that.

Comment: I can do that (call my SynchProc) from Thread, but can't do that from object of other class, that is in ThreadClass object. It's a my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand, but I think you have a situation like this. You have a `TThread` descendent, say `TMyThread`. And that class in turn uses another class named `TThreadClass` which does not descend from `TThread`. You want to call `Synchronize` from a method of `TThreadClass`.

Here are some options:

1. Pass the `TThread` instance to `TThreadClass`. This is a rather brutal solution to the problem. Now `TThreadClass` can do anything to the thread when all it wants to do is call `Synchronize`.
2. Pass a procedural variable referring to the `Synchronize` method to `TThreadClass`. This gives `TThreadClass` the ability to do what it needs and no more.
3. Call the `TThread.Synchronize` class method passing `nil` for the first parameter.

Of these, the final option is the simplest. You can do it like this:

```
procedure TThreadClass.SynchProc(P: TThreadProcedure);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, P);
end;
```

Note that it is not a good idea to pass in a `TProc` and cast to `TThreadProcedure` as per the code in the question. Force the caller to pass in a procedural variable of the right type. In this case the cast is benign, but you should always aim to avoid casts.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I create a simple program, that implement that and it successfully works. That I will search some errors or ... something else, that hinder to do it in my main program. Thanks for help. If I do not find a solution, I'll be back to your options for solving the problem. Otherwise - I'll write why it is not possible to make

Comment: Whether or not you can make your program work is beyond the scope of the question. You simply asked how to call Synchronize from somewhere other than a TThread instance method.

Comment: Thank you for answers. My error was that I declare my second class in objects, that runned in main thread of program (it created there and object of this is property of Form). I would to use methods of my second class with Synch, but it was not necessary - obj of second class was in main thread! but ... some time my programm work good and   cycles in sec class (that must to retard program) didn't do it!